# Borrar y renderizar datatables

Tags: javascript, html, datatable

Como puedo hacer para mostrar una datatable con algún boton? Intenté con esta función

```
function genera_tabla() {
  var body = document.getElementById("bodyTabla");
  body.innerHTML = `<table id="example2" class="class="table table-bordered table-striped table-sm"" width="100%"></table> `};
```

Pero no me la renderiza ni muestra ningún error en consola. La tabla ya la tengo creada y si coloco la etiqueta table en el html se visualiza, pero quiero poder llamarla con algún boton y que recién ahí se muestre.

Mi tabla:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example2').DataTable( {
    columns: [
        { "data": "MODELO" },
        {
            "data": "Monto", render: function (data, type, row) {
                return type === 'export' ?
                    data.replaceAll(/[$ |.]/g, '').replace(',', '.') :
                    data;
            }
        }, 
       
    ]
} );
```

} )

Comment: meter el datatable en un div, y controlar su display hide/block no te es suficiente?

Comment: Faltan datos para darte una buena respuesta. Deberias poner un html mínimo donde aparezca el botón y la forma en que estas llamando a `genera_tabla` cuando lo pulsas.  Aun así, a ojímetro, diria que el DataTable se ejecuta durante la carga del html y no encuentra el id example2 y no lo crea en ninguna parte, y luego, al pulsar el botón y creas el elemento con ese id ya da igual pues no parece que lo esté esperando y no lo intenta de nuevo.  Quizas deberias poner la creación del datatable dentro de `genera_tabla`, por probar.